# How to fast copy and paste from filtered range

Tags: excel, vba, performance

This loops over at least 100 times (100+ models), and it currently takes nearly 15 minutes. How can I speed up the copying from visible filtered cells and pasting to reduce the time to seconds? `data` is another workbook.

```
        Dim last_row As Long
        last_row = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Enter models").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Dim models() As Variant
        models = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Enter models").Range("B2:B" & last_row).Value
        With data
            Dim last_row_src As Long
            last_row_src = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Dim model As Variant
            Dim last_row_dest As Long
            Dim start_time As Date
            start_time = Now()
            Dim end_time As Date
            For Each model In models
                .Range("$A$3:$BP$3").AutoFilter Field:=20, Criteria1:=model
                last_row_dest = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("PO Tracker").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
                'appends to last empty row in PO Tracker worksheet
                'product ID
                On Error Resume Next
                .Range("T4:T" & last_row_src).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PO Tracker").Range("A" & last_row_dest).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                'PO
                On Error Resume Next
                .Range("W4:W" & last_row_src).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PO Tracker").Range("B" & last_row_dest).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                'SAP status
                On Error Resume Next
                Set src_range = .Range("BJ4:BJ" & last_row_src).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PO Tracker").Range("C" & last_row_dest).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                'delivery number
                On Error Resume Next
                .Range("X4:X" & last_row_src).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PO Tracker").Range("D" & last_row_dest).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                'order quantity
                On Error Resume Next
                .Range("F4:F" & last_row_src).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PO Tracker").Range("I" & last_row_dest).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                'expected delivery date
                On Error Resume Next
                .Range("I4:I" & last_row_src).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PO Tracker").Range("M" & last_row_dest).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                'expected GI date
                On Error Resume Next
                .Range("J4:J" & last_row_src).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
                ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PO Tracker").Range("N" & last_row_dest).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
                .ShowAllData
            Next
            end_time = Now()
            Debug.Print end_time - start_time
         End With
```

Comment: Why are you trying to filter multiple times and copy each filter range when you could use `Sort` based on `Column B` values and then copy the full range in one go? Or better yet use `advanced filter sort` then copy/paste

Comment: @gmalc good suggestion. I wasn't aware of advanced filter sort. Can you please post it as an answer with some code so I try it out then can mark it solved.

Comment: It would be better for you if you do a search, and then try to accomplish the `Filter Sort` and if you run into any issues ask another question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per GMalc's suggestion I used `AdvancedFilter` to reduce from 15+ min to 2 min since I don't have to loop anymore.

```
     With data
            Dim last_row_src As Long
            last_row_src = .Range("A" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            Dim model As Variant
            Dim last_row_dest As Long
            Dim start_time As Date
            start_time = Now()
            Dim end_time As Date
            Dim last_row_models As Long
            last_row_models = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Enter models").Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
            .Range("T3").Value2 = "Item"
            .Range("A3:BP" & last_row_src).AdvancedFilter Action:=xlFilterInPlace, CriteriaRange:=ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Enter models").Range("B1:B" & last_row_models)
        'product ID
        On Error Resume Next
        .Range("T4:T" & last_row_src).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PO Tracker").Range("A2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        'PO
        .Range("W4:W" & last_row_src).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PO Tracker").Range("B2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        'SAP status
        .Range("BJ4:BJ" & last_row_src).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PO Tracker").Range("C2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        'delivery number
        .Range("X4:X" & last_row_src).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PO Tracker").Range("D2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        'order quantity
        .Range("F4:F" & last_row_src).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PO Tracker").Range("I2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        'expected delivery date
        .Range("I4:I" & last_row_src).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PO Tracker").Range("M2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        'expected GI date
        .Range("J4:J" & last_row_src).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Copy
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets("PO Tracker").Range("N2").PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        .ShowAllData
        end_time = Now()
        Debug.Print end_time - start_time
   End With
```